# Why use prevState to replace a list value React JS

Tags: react-native

I just wanted a clarification on this

```
state = {
    foodList: [],
    currentFoodItem: null,
}

onFoodsReceived = (foodList) => {
    console.log(foodList);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        foodList: prevState.foodList = foodList
    }));
}
```

In the above code it uses a prevState to replace a list value when u can use the code below. Why some uses prevstate while others don't to replace a list value

```
onFoodsReceived = (foodList) => {
    console.log(foodList);
    this.setState({
        foodList: foodList
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is used when we want to override the current state with the last state's parameters.

From React docs :

According to the React docs "React may batch multiple `setState()` calls into a single update for performance. Because `this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state."

"To fix it, use a second form of `setState()` that accepts a function rather than an object. That function will receive the previous state as the first argument, and the props at the time the update is applied as the second argument"

[Sources](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).